# "Fixing" a dropped LCD screen

Tags: lcd

This morning I dropped my laptop, and as a result have the image below. Is there anything I can do to at least be able to see the screen without having to plug it in to an external monitor?

[image: Dropped LCD Screen]

Comment: I know it doesn't help or anything, but that's a pretty cool image!

Comment: @Azz Indeed it is! I've kept my broken laptop screen because of cool image!

Comment: I beleive the technical term is "that screen is FUBAR" I'm afraid a full replacement is the only viable option.

Comment: Take a high-res picture, it looks cooler than most of the other [broken LCD wallpapers](http://www.google.com/images?q=broken+LCD+wallpaper) I've seen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it is impossible to economically fix that screen. The effect you are seeing is caused by breaking conductors inside the screen. Basically, [TFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD) screens have horizontal and vertical conductors inside for each row and column of pixels (second image on the link). Once the connection is cut, pixels from the breakpoint are uncontrollable. If you press the screen in certain places, you might temporarily restore the function of some pixels, but as soon as pressure is removed, they will go off-line.

Comment: The connections broke, but that's secondary to the broken substrate they're on (the glass).  Totally irreparable.

Answer (score 7):

You will not be able to repair the screen itself in order to make it "viewable",  the best you will be able to do is to replace the screen itself from somewhere like http://www.accupart.co.uk/

You may be able to find a guide on the internet on how to replace your screen or you can send it out for replacement.

Answer (score 6):

You could ssh or remote desktop into it if you had set it up before hand. Otherwise an external monitor is your best bet.

Good news is there are a plethora of good sites now that can walk you through a laptop screen  replacement. And the cost of LCD's is not as prohibitively expensive as they once were.

Comment: Yes, I've replace a screen myself. As long as you follow instructions (and don't lose a small screw in the process), it's quite straightforward.

Comment: Also, be aware that an official (i.e. from the manufacturer) replacement LCD screen is often prohibitively expensive. But people often sell old, functioning screens on eBay etc. (or just buy a broken laptop with an undamaged screen).

Answer (score -1):

There is a way out. I dropped my usb3 external ASUS monitor. It showed storage colours. I found that pressing the back of the monitor shows correct colour. So I put it face down on the table. Pressed the back in straight strokes with a soft cloth, gradually covering the whole back.
The monitor is now back to original colours.

Comment: It's worth trying this sort of thing before giving up, but I'm 99.999% sure this will not work for the screen shown, because I can see where the liquid has leaked out of the "liquid crystal display" (which is what LCD stands for).  Gentle pressure won't undo that leaking.